# Help with custom iterator

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with my custom iterator...it seems that the `next()` method is not working.

I think my constructor is not working...and I got this error message: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class RandomBag <Item> implements Iterable<Item>
{
  private Node first;
  private int N;
  private int k=0;

  private class Node
  {
    Item item;
    Node next;
  }

  public void add(Item item)
  {
    Node oldfirst = first;
    first = new Node();
    first.item = item;
    first.next = oldfirst;
    N++;
  }

  public boolean isEmpty()
  {
    return first == null;
  }

  public int size()
  {
    return N;
  }

  public Iterator<Item> iterator()
  {
    return new RandomIterator();
  }

  private class RandomIterator implements Iterator<Item>
  {    
    Item[] a = (Item[]) new Object [N];

    public RandomIterator()
    {
      int counter = 0;

      //put items in the array
      for (Node x=first; x!=null; x=x.next)
      {
        a[counter] = x.item;
        counter++;
      }

      //randomize the items in the array
      for (int i=0; i<size(); i++)
      {
        int randomIndex = StdRandom.uniform(i, size());
        Item item = a[randomIndex];
        a[randomIndex] = a[i];
        a[i] = item;
      }
    }

    public void remove() {}

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
      return k!=N;
    }

    public Item next()
    {
      Item item = a[k % a.length];
      k++;
      return item;
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    RandomBag<Double> numbers = new RandomBag<Double>();
    Iterator iter = numbers.iterator();

    numbers.add(1.0);
    numbers.add(4.0);
    numbers.add(3.0);
    numbers.add(5.0);

    StdOut.println(iter.next());
    StdOut.println(iter.next());
    StdOut.println(iter.next());
    StdOut.println(iter.next());
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the exception?  Which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: This is the line: Item item = a[k % a.length];

Comment: what i am trying to do is to modify the bag iterator next() method. So that every time the next() is called, it will return an random but non-repeated item from the bag

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in this method:

```
public Item next()
{
  Item item = a[k % a.length]; // If a.length is zero... BOOM
  k++;
  return item;
}
```

Comment: And, importantly, `N` is used as the dimension of `a` and it seems to not be initialized meaning it will be 0.  Presumably the iterator is being used before anything is added to the bag.

Comment: but, my RandomIterator() constructor should initialize and give value to the constructor. I am sure that I added stuffs inside the bag. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: The k variable should be part of the iterator and NOT of the class itself - otherwise you get obviously pretty useless results as soon as you have more than 1 iterator.

But the problem is that you use a argument less constructor for your RandomBag class which means that N is initialized to 0. Then you construct your inner class iterator with an array of size N (=0) and try to use it - that won't work. The add() methods after initializing your Iterator have absolutely no effect - which makes this iterator pretty useless (usually you should throw a concurrent modification exception here and use the data of the datastructure not make a copy=)

PS: If you want to use this strange iterator, change your hasNext() method to use your arrays length and NOT N - that'll fix this issue because next() will not be called (or if it is, throwing an exception is fine)

Comment: I still don't understand the issues, but now it works fine, thank you guys very much.

Comment: You're using the current size of the array in your main class to access an array that was copied earlier on which has a different size. If you don't understand, either step through your code with a debugger - or better yet (good exercise) think the code through and at every step write down the important state of a) the RandomBag instance and b) of your iterator. That should make the problem clear.

Comment: I am still new to java, so I do not know how to use debugger

Comment: Then do it in your head (a bit paper can't harm though) - just as I solved that problem. Way better exercise anyhow for someone new to programming :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't protect you against this error in the future with a zero-length bag (or some of the other code issues pointed out), but moving this line:

```
Iterator iter = numbers.iterator();
```

Below the final .`add()` statement should fix the issue you're seeing, which is occurring because the iterator is initializing before anything is in `numbers`.

Comment: I did what you say, but it still gives me the same error message.

Comment: @help I tried it myself and it works after making the fix so you're doing something wrong.  You just need to create the iterator **after** it has elements.

Comment: yes, now it works, I think there is something wrong with the hasNext() too, which someone pointed out to me. Thank you guys very much. My head is already exploding.

Comment: yeah, your code has other issues. I always recommend inspecting the JDK source for how it's done there when doing things like that -- you'll learn a lot. ArrayList.java is probably where you could get some help.